# In RSA, what if we get pInv instead of qInv?

Tags: rsa, openssl

I'm following the discussion in the [question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/18084/in-rsa-why-does-p-have-to-be-bigger-than-q-where-n-p-times-q) about RSA and what if we set $p<q$.

So, what if we mistakenly let $p<q$ and proceed with the private keys creations; that is, we pick up $p, q, e$ and derive from them: $dP,dQ, qInv$ (I'm using the CRT key structure in [PKCS#1](https://www.cryptrec.go.jp/en/cryptrec_03_spec_cypherlist_files/PDF/pkcs-1v2-12.pdf)).

So, by trying to create those private-key elements, and forcing $p<q$, I see that they differ from those created when $p > q$, by the following:

1. $dP$ and $dQ$ values are swapped;
2. $qInv$ is calculated as $p^{-1} \bmod q$ instead of $q^{-1} \bmod p$.

My question: if some adversary asks the key owner to sign a chosen message $m$ and the owner:

- First comes out with the ciphertext $c_{wrong}$, created from $p<q$;
- So, the adversary complains that the signature verification is failing.
- Finally, the owner fix .1 and .2 above, and give $c_{correct}$.

Can the adversary gain any advantage from learning $c_{wrong}$ and $c_{correct}$?

Comment: With their private key, the key owner would not _encrypt_. They would _sign_. In asymmetric cryptography, encryption always uses the public key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm following the discussion in the question about RSA and what if we set $p<q$

Nothing bad will happen - the CRT algorithm we use doesn't actually depend on $p > q$ - it'll work both ways.

The standard algorithm to perform the final CRT step is:

$$m = m_q + q \cdot ((m_p - m_q) \cdot qinv \bmod p)$$

(where $m_p = c^{d_p} \bmod p$ and $m_q = c^{d_q} \bmod q$)

It is easy to see that $0 \le m < pq$ (if $0 \le m_p < p$ and $0 \le m_q < q$) and that $m = m_q \bmod q$ and (given $q \cdot qinv = 1 \bmod p$ ) that $m = m_p \bmod p$.

Because $p, q$ are relatively prime, there is only one such $m$ which meets all three criteria, and hence $m$ must be the proper decryption.

Note that none of the steps used the relative magnitude of $p$ and $q$ - they would all be true for either ordering.

> So, the adversary complains that the decryption is failing.

Why would decryption fail?

> Can the adversary gain any advantage from learning $c_{wrong}$ and $c_{correct}$?

Those are both valid ciphertexts; RSA (with correct padding) is CCA secure, and so there is no advantage.

The obvious follow-up question would be:

```
Why then did they specify that p > q in the first place?
```

Dunno - the question you linked to gives some plausible reasons why it might make an implementation easier.

Comment: when I said "encrypt", I was thinking in "signing". So, does it make sense to say that the signature verification would fail?

Comment: @oCriptoPanquer: why would signature verification fail?  You're using a perfectly valid private key.

Comment: let's suppose $p⋅=1 \bmod q$ is used instead of  $⋅=1 \bmod$ Let's assume a bad implementation of OpenSSL.

Comment: @oCriptoPanquer: in that case (assuming deterministic signatures), the private key can easily be recovered.  In that case, $m_{correct} = m_{wrong} \pmod q$ but $m_{correct} \ne m_{wrong} \pmod p$, hence computing $\gcd( n, m_{correct} - m_{wrong})$ immediately yields a factor ($q$)

Comment: @oCriptoPanquer: The only case I know where $p>q$ matters is in implementations that compute $m_p-m_q\bmod p$ as $m_p-m_q+p\bmod p$ and wrongly assume $m_p-m_q+p\ge0$ (where $m_p=c^{d_p}\bmod p$ and  $m_q=c^{d_q}\bmod q$). But AFAIK that does not happen with OpenSSL.

Comment: I didn't get one detail: even when we have $m_{correct} = m_q + p(m_p - m_q).qInv \bmod p$ and $m_{wrong} = m_p + q(m_q - m_p).pInv \bmod q$, we can say that $m_{correct} = m_{wrong} \bmod q$? (one have *qInv* and the other *pInv*)